# Detect Mobile from Saved User Agent in MySQL only

Tags: mysql

Let's say we have User agents saved in a MySQL field in a table like this

Table: **visit**

> id (int)
>
> useragent (varchar 255)

Let's say we have 100k records saved and we have to find out how many of them are mobile devices and how many are computers, is there a way in MySQL to query that information? I know how to do it in PHP and can easily do so, but in this case we need to figure that out from the stored data via a query and not use any programming language to parse the returned data. Just pure MySQL

For example in PHP You could use something like

```
function detectMobile() 
{
 
$mobile_browser = '0';
 
if (preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|android)/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}
 
if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}    
 
$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));
$mobile_agents = array(
    'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
    'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
    'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
    'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
    'newt','noki','oper','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
    'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
    'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
    'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
    'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');
 
if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}
 
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']),'OperaMini') > 0) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}
 
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'windows') > 0) {
    $mobile_browser = 0;
}

if(strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'ipad') > 0)
{
    $mobile_browser++;
}



 
if ($mobile_browser > 0) {
   return true;
}
else {
   return false;
}   
 
}
```

Comment: It would help if you told us how you'd do it with PHP.

Comment: In PHP, we would run a regex check against a list of known mobile device user agents and get an almost certain answer, but I have no clue how to run those multiple regex in a MySQL query without involving PHP

Answer (score 4):

I have used the below sql to count the number or tablets, mobile and other devices. Use the `Like` query as is more optimized than using regex.

```
SELECT 
COUNT( * ) total, 
COUNT( IF( useragent LIKE '%tablet%' or useragent LIKE '%ipad%', 1, NULL ) ) AS tablets,
COUNT( IF( useragent LIKE '%mobile%' AND useragent NOT LIKE '%tablet%' AND useragent NOT LIKE '%ipad%', 1, NULL ) ) AS mobile,
COUNT( IF( useragent  NOT LIKE '%tablet%' AND useragent  NOT LIKE '%ipad%' AND useragent  NOT LIKE '%mobile%', 1, NULL ) ) AS other
FROM visit
```

Comment: I found out that this worked pretty well, but because user_agents mimic each other all the time, is it valid to do it by simply checking tablet, ipad and mobile?